# Arrange a matrix with regard to the rownames and colnames

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, subset

Image we have a matrix, M*N, M rows and N columns, like

```
  b a d c e
a 2 1 4 3 5
b 3 2 5 4 6
c 1 3 3 2 4
```

I want to write a function, where take the above matrix, return the following matrix:

```
  a b c d e
a 1 2 3 4 5
b 2 3 4 5 6
c 3 1 2 3 4
```

Where the first part of the matrix M*M， 3*3 in this case is symmetric in terms of rownames and colnames, and 3*5 in total, the rest 3*2 matrix is pushed afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an N x M matrix where N <= M and all row names are contained in col names, this will bring the columns with names existing in row names to the front in the same order as the row names, and leave the rest of the columns in their original order after that:

```
mat_ord <- function(mx) mx[, c(rownames(mx), setdiff(colnames(mx), rownames(mx)))]
mat_ord(mx)
```

produces:

```
  a b c d e
a 1 2 3 4 5
b 2 3 4 5 6
c 3 1 2 3 4
```

To see the difference, consider `mx2` which has rows and columns ordered differently than mx:

```
  e a b d c
b 6 2 3 5 4
a 5 1 2 4 3
c 4 3 1 3 2
```

And with `mat_ord(mx2)` we get:

```
  b a c e d
b 3 2 4 6 5
a 2 1 3 5 4
c 1 3 2 4 3
```

**UPDATE:** this sorts rows and columns while ensuring symmetry on first N cols/rows:

```
mat_ord2 <- function(mx) mx[sort(rownames(mx)), c(sort(rownames(mx)), sort(setdiff(colnames(mx), rownames(mx))))]
mat_ord2(mx2)
```

produces:

```
  a b c d e
a 1 2 3 4 5
b 2 3 4 5 6
c 3 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: thank you so much, would you mind to put the original one ? I can sort  them as alphabet order first, then rearrange them.

Comment: @ToBeGeek, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "original one".  Do you want the result of `mat_ord(mx2)` to look like `mat_ord(mx)` (i.e. match rows to columns to make symmetric, but also make sure everything is ordered)?

Comment: Yes, like that, make the rows names ordered, and also the colnames are ordered and the first nrow*nrow part of the whole matrix is symmetric.